# ShowAsAction icon showing in preview but not in emulator

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am newbie in android development, So just going through the training tutorial available in official site. I am trying to add `Action button` in `Action Bar` using following code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MyActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"        
    app:showAsAction ="ifRoom"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Icon showing in `preview` but while running `emulator Nexus 5 Lollipop`, it is just showing Overflow icon.

This is my `manifest` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.rajeev.myfirstapp" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="22"></uses-sdk>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.rajeev.myfirstapp.MyActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: `Should use app:showAsAction with the appcompat library with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" less... (Ctrl+F1) 
When using the appcompat library, menu resources should refer to the showAsAction in the app: namespace, not the android: namespace.  Similarly, when not using the appcompat library, you should be using the android:showAsAction attribute.`

Comment: Ignore that message, run your app and check the result :)

Comment: I think it's just a warning, not error. In fact, your app can run without any error, right?

Comment: Android studio complains that it is error instead, but somehow compile it and run it in emulator.. Still looking for some good explanation from some one who has knowledge over it

Comment: `<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_overflow"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="123"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource">
    </item>
</menu>`